How to display WooCommerce product category description in the head
I want to display de category description in a meta tag but my code does not return the category description but the description of the first product of the store page
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    if( is_product_category() ){
        $catID = get_the_category();
        echo category_description( $catID[0] );
    } else 
        $description = get_the_content();
        if ( $description) {
            echo wp_strip_all_tags($description);
        }
    ?>"/>




There are some mistakes in your code:

To get the product category term ID used in a product category archive page use the WordPress function get_queried_object_id(),
There are missing brackets after the ELSE statement,
You should also use WordPress is_singular() conditional function to target single post and product pages,

Try to use the following instead:
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    // Target Product category archives
    if( is_product_category() ) {
        $description = category_description( get_queried_object_id() );
    } 
    // Target single post and product pages
    elseif ( is_singular( array( 'post', 'product' ) ) ) {
        $description = get_the_content();
    }
    // Display description
    if ( isset($description) && $description ) {
        echo wp_strip_all_tags( $description );
    }
    ?>"/>

It should work.
If you want to target only single product pages (but not blog posts too), replace the line:
elseif ( is_singular( array( 'post', 'product' ) ) ) {

with:
elseif ( is_product() ) {


get_queried_object_id() will retrieves the current queried id.
$category->term_id Accesses the ID of the current category, which is then used to fetch the category description.
get_the_excerpt() function retrieves the excerpt for the current post. If the post does not have a manual excerpt, it generates one from the post content.
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $category_term_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $description = category_description( $category_term_id ); 
    } else {
        $description = get_the_excerpt();
    }

    if ( $description ) {
        echo wp_strip_all_tags(truncate_text($description));
    }
    ?>"/>

Function for truncate the description to 160
function truncate_text($text, $max_length = 160) {
    if (strlen($text) > $max_length) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, $max_length) . '...';
    }
    return $text;
}

